# Finding the conditional probability of an event without indication if the events are independent.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I'm studying an introductory statistics textbook and, unfortunately, it doesn't come with an answer key. The textbook gave this problem, which I've spending hours trying to figure out:

"Roll two fair dice separately. Each die has six faces.

a. List the sample space.

b. Let A be the event that either a three or four is rolled first, followed by an even number. Find P(A).

c. Let B be the event that the sum of the two rolls is at most seven. Find P(B).

d. Find P(A|B)."

My answers to questions b and c are P(A) = $\frac{6}{36}$ and P(B) = $\frac{21}{36}$. I can't for the life of me figure out how to calculate P(A|B) since I don't know if the events are dependent in which I would be using the formula P(A|B) = $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ or if they're independent meaning I would then be using the formula P(A|B) = P(A)P(B). Can someone please explain how I would go about calculating this problem?

Comment: You have the explicit events.  What rolls comprise $A$?  Which comprise $B$?

Comment: What do you mean by explicit events?

Comment: I just mean, there is no need at all to rely on any formulas.  List the $21$ rolls that comprise $B$ (or describe them in some way that lets you avoid listing them).  How many of those are  also  in $A$?

Comment: But wouldn't that take longer for problems that have larger sample space? Is there a formula for calculating this without writing it all out?

Comment: It takes less than $5$ seconds to do this explicitly.  Just try.  As a general matter, there could never be a single sensible formula that worked for every possible restriction on a big sample space.

Comment: That means if, for example, a problem had a bigger sample space and more restrictions, there would be no formula and I would have to list it all out?

Comment: Well, you';d have to look at the problem explicitly.  Different methods apply to different problems.  There are no one-size-fits-all methods.

Comment: It would be pretty boring if the same tools applied to every problem.